# Почему в проекте Tomcat сразу не отражаются изменения в классах сервлетов?

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat

Здравствуйте.

Работаю в IDEA 2017.1, пишу приложение под Tomcat (использую 9.0.0.M19), тестирую в браузере Google Chrome Версия 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit).

Заметил сегодня одну "мелочь", когда писал сервлет для upload файла на сервер.
Вношу изменения в сервлет, деплою, мне приложение продолжает возвращать ошибку, которой уже по идее не должно быть.
Ковырялся в коде, пытался найти ошибку, ничего.
Потом предпринял попытку - вытер полностью проект из WabApps Tomcat и IDEA его разлила заново и ошибки ушли.

Почему сразу не применяются изменения в классах сервлетов? Что не так?

p.s.
настройка деплоя

[image: настройка деплоя]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

настройка артефакта

[image: настройка артефакта]

проверяю визуально изменения в каталоге с классами, дата свежая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

для исключения факторов - кеширования буфера и т.д. запустил из IE11 (до этого не использовался), проблема воспроизводится и там.

В предыдущих версиях вроде бы такого не замечалось по моим ощущениям...

Comment: вы показали настройку сервера, а не deployment. покажите настройку deployment.

Comment: добавил настройку deployment